# Webview - Initial startup delay

Tags: android, performance, webview

I'm working on an Android app, that uses a webview to display maps.
The performance isn't too bad, I can zoom/pan without bigger delays..
But it takes an irresponsible time to start up. (Not to load the page! to start up the webview..)

Here is an example from my logcat:

```
10-25 12:33:46.212: I opened the webview
10-25 12:34:03.062: onLoadResource() - the first JS file gets loaded
10-25 12:34:10.062: Page is fully loaded
```

So in my eyes, it takes ~17s to start up the webview, but only 7 to load the page.

Any idea what the issue could be?

**Edit:**

```
 WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
 settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true); 
 settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
 settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
 settings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

 final Activity activity = this;
 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
     public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
         callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
     }
 });
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url){
     System.out.println(url);

   }
 });

 webview.addJavascriptInterface(JavascriptInterface, "Android");
 webview.loadUrl("mywebpage");

 setContentView(webview);
```

Comment: Can you post your code for where you initialise/load the webview?

Comment: yes sure, i've updated it.

Comment: Thanks, and what about `JavascriptInterface`, where is that initialised?

Comment: There is nothing special about the interface, that shouldn't be causing the issues.

Comment: Have the same issue. By the way it is applied only for the first WebView initialization. But when close fragment with WebView and open it again - initialization become 5x faster.

Comment: Yes, it is try that the first web view creation for the app process takes little bit of time. It internally loads some libraries that takes that time.